# Plug in a figure into one of the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have a grid of subplots in matplotlib.
For most of them I define what the subplot will be as normal.
For one of them, there is some logic going on that I have encapsulated inside a function `distribution_of_graphs`.

Can I use the figure that that function returns to be plot as one of the subplots?

```
def distribution_of_graphs(net):

    # Some logic to get df from net object
    df = net.logic()

    pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(len(list(df)), rot=-.25, light=.7)
    g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="grad", hue="grad", aspect=15, height=5, palette=pal)

    # Draw the densities in a few steps
    g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=0.6, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
    g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2) ## White contour
    g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False) ## Will serve as the x axis

    # Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
    def label(x, color, label):
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
                ha="left", va="bottom", transform=ax.transAxes)
        ax.set_xlim([-1.5, 1.5])
    g.map(label, "x")

    # Set the subplots to overlap
    g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.75)

    # Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
    g.set_titles("")
    g.set(yticks=[])
    g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
    return g
```

This function creates the following image: 
[image]

I will like to use the resulting plot of that function to be the ax4 of the next figure:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 0), colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 1), colspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 0), colspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (2, 0), colspan=2)
sns.lineplot(xaxis, net.weight_stats['gradWinp'], ax=ax1, color='blue').set_title('grad W1')
sns.lineplot(xaxis, net.weight_stats['gradWout'], ax=ax2, color='red').set_title('grad W2')
sns.lineplot(xaxis, net.weight_stats['gradWinp'], ax=ax3, color='blue', label='grad W1')
sns.lineplot(xaxis, net.weight_stats['gradWout'], ax=ax3, color='red', label='grad W2')

# What I am missing
ax4.plot(distribution_of_graphs(net))

# Previos behavior working properly
#sns.kdeplot(norm_dW1, shade=True, ax=ax4)
#sns.kdeplot(norm_dW2, shade=True, ax=ax4)

plt.plot()
```

It is now leaving that space in blank and created the plot from the function in a separate figure:

[image]
With the error message: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'FacetGrid'`

Thanks!

Comment: You would rather not use a FacetGrid in this case but instead of `ax4` create 4 different axes in your figure and plot the kdeplots to them. If you need help with that, I would suggest you provide a [mcve] (i.e. a runnable code) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) You can plot inside a function. As a simple example,

```
def plotxy(x,y):
    plot(x,y)
    return

subplot(4,1,3)
plotxy(x,y) # will plot in the 4th subplot
```

2) Pass the axis handle into your function

```
def plotxy(ax,x,y):
    ax.plot(x,y)
    return

plotxy(ax4,x,y)
```